# Copy excel (.xls) file to a container using the Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I am fairly new to Docker so my question may have a simple answer. Via the Dockerfile which i created using some online Tutorials I successfully integrated my java project into a container. Now i want to do the same for a .xls file. I have looked for a solution all over already existing threads, but could not find any.

One class uses an .xls file to generate information for my app services. 
Eveything works just fine (it's a Spring app and postman and h2 db provide good tests) 
In this case my Dockerfile looks like the trunk of code below.
I only provide two of my "guinea pigs".
One where i try to access the excel file via its type (the jar file seems to be accessed that way).
I have also tried to Copy by using the File name since this seems more natural. (Although the Jar file did not seem to cause any problems on its own.)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG JAR_FILE

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

COPY ${XLS_FILE}  test.xls

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Dserver.port=80" , "-Dprofile=prod", "/app.jar"]
```

---

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG JAR_FILE

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

COPY ${TaIlagerplatz_KR}  test.xls

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Dserver.port=80" , "-Dprofile=prod", "/app.jar"]
```

I have had more inconclusive explorations/experiments.I'm kind of at my programming limits..:)
I turns out that get "an invalid or corrupt jar" error for the first attempt.
The message reads

```
C:\Users\dnorthe\Java Tutorial\RGLVS_BE_Core>docker run test3
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar
```

the second, more sophisticated error message reads:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/Data/TaIlagerplatz_KR.xls (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at de.biere.rglvs.artikelstamm.init.SeedDataArtikelExcel.read(SeedDataArtikelExcel.java:39)
        at de.biere.rglvs.artikelstamm.init.SeedDataArtikelExcel.<clinit>(SeedDataArtikelExcel.java:30)
        at de.biere.rglvs.artikelstamm.init.DataLoaderArtikel.run(DataLoaderArtikel.java:27)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:794)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at de.biere.rglvs.RglvsApplication.main(RglvsApplication.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/Data/TaIlagerplatz_KR.xls (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at de.biere.rglvs.lager.init.SeedDataLoaderLagerplatzExcel.read(SeedDataLoaderLagerplatzExcel.java:36)
        at de.biere.rglvs.lager.init.SeedDataLoaderLagerplatzExcel.<clinit>(SeedDataLoaderLagerplatzExcel.java:27)
        at de.biere.rglvs.lager.init.DataLoaderLagerplatz.run(DataLoaderLagerplatz.java:27)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:794)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at de.biere.rglvs.RglvsApplication.main(RglvsApplication.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Along with some other spring injection problems. if needed i can post the whole error message(it extends over a few pages). also i am not sure if i posted the code correctly on this site - sorry in advance!!..

Comment: Your path is wrong. What makes you think the file is in `build/...`? That looks like the path in your local machine. My best advice is it hang the container and docker exec into it. Have a look around. Try and understand the problem yourself. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how docker works and just giving you the fix for this won't help correct that.

Comment: The file is in "build" because i put it there in my own directory.. I understand that this can not work. My java class that accesses it uses a relative path. You are right, i do not understand docker all to well, but this is why i need at least some more hints. My understanding of docker is that is a container which can run the app. But in order to run it, it needs to now how to access it. but i can't seem to find what actually works. "test.xls" in this syntax is supposed to be the files name in the docker image. what is the correct syntax? i also tried "COPY filepath newfilename". failed.

Comment: i understand that in order to access the file from the container it should have the same name as in my directory, so i also tried that. So that the java class can access it from the container. Thing is, in my understanding, the .jar and .xls file are stored on the same storage level in the container. whereas in my app they have different directories so the commands that access the files in my class look in the same place not knowing the file is in different places depending on whether its on the image or my local directory. please correct me if i am wrong. as i said, i am new to this.

Comment: Does your suggestion imply i should use the .yml file? I don't understand why it would be a difference, except for that it is executed before the dockerfile. Do you mean that by "hang the container onto it"? Onto what exactly? the image? In the .yml file i should be able to define the dependency from the .xls file. 
Did i get the problem right?

Comment: Danny, can u pls tell how did u solve it. I am new to all this and have exactly same requirement

Comment: @user1731045 hi i did not solve it. sorry:(

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for posting without explanation.

Currently Dockerfiles of yours will create directory "app.jar" and copy the app.jar inside there.Meanwhile the Entrypoint will look for /app.jar and instead will find a directory by name app.jar and thereby throwing a corrupt jar error.

Remedy is to copy the app.jar directly to /

This should work.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG JAR_FILE

ARG XLS_FILE

COPY ${JAR_FILE} ${XLS_FILE} /

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Dserver.port=80" , "-Dprofile=prod", "/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Why should this work? What should this do? Why does the OPs code not work? Code only answers are discouraged exactly for this reason.

Comment: does not work. "Error: invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar ". I still don't see how my class in the container knows where and how it can access the .xls file